# Last-of type is not applied

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I've a really strange problem. My goal is to create 3 equal-width spans. The first two have an internal right padding, the last doesn't have. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="span1of3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc risus nibh, sagittis vitae pharetra at, varius venenatis justo.</div>
<div class="span1of3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc risus nibh, sagittis vitae pharetra at, varius venenatis justo.</div>
<div class="span1of3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc risus nibh, sagittis vitae pharetra at, varius venenatis justo.</div>
```

CSS

```
.span1of3 {
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-right:-4px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.span1of3 {
    width:33.3%;
    padding-right:50px;
}

.span1of3:last-of-type{
    padding-right:0px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

When I refresh the page, I see for an instant the last span red background, and it immediately turns to blank. I was convinced I was creating a general style for `span1of3` and then specify something particular for the last span, but it doesn't work. Why?

**EDIT**

This is the complete HTML code (span.css was already completely pasted above)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/base/css/span.css" media="all" type="text/css" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />

</head>

<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">


    <div class="span1of3">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc risus nibh, sagittis vitae pharetra at, varius venenatis justo. 
    </div>
    <div class="span1of3">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc risus nibh, sagittis vitae pharetra at, varius venenatis justo. 
    </div>
    <div class="span1of3">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc risus nibh, sagittis vitae pharetra at, varius venenatis justo. 
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: everything seems to work as it should in this fiddle with the code you provide : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/F4qmA/

Comment: What browser are you experiencing this behavior in? It appears to work correctly in Chrome/FF/IE11. Is there any conflicting JS? http://jsfiddle.net/U39jp/

Comment: Seems to work for me as well. Also, you should note that using this method creates three sections of non-equal width (the first two are narrower than the last one) because of the padding.

Comment: @AlfredXing False, because he is using border-box.

Comment: `:last-of-type` operates on elements, not classes. So if your structure is different from what you have above, then you may get different results. Or, if you have other CSS, or JavaScript, that may be overriding your CSS.

Comment: Working fine with me on jsfiddle as others said, so it seems to be browser specific, can you test it on different browsers and update your question plz?

Comment: If you have a flash of unstyled content (or in this case, styled content) the style probably is getting overridden by CSS in an external stylesheet.

Comment: @BramVanroy Sorry, I meant the width of the **content**. They are all 33% width, but the first two have 50px padding, so the content width of those two are (33% - 50px) while the last one is just the 33%.

Comment: I am testing the code with chrome version 34.0.1847.137... it sounds really strange, I see your fiddle working... could it be a browser bug? I don't have other css and/or js which may conflict.

Comment: @Giorgio I don't think so. I think there's more to your webpage than the small snippet of code you're showing here.

Comment: @Giorgio j08691's remark could be the key too. Do you have Javascript or something that creates other divs after this snippet?

Comment: @MrLister I've just edited the question and added the complete HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on j98691 invaluable comment I suggest the following code

```
<div id="spanned">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Then the CSS would be

```css
#spanned span {
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-right:-4px;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:33.3%;
    padding-right:50px;
}

#spanned span:last-of-type{
    padding-right:0px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Edit:

Your CSS had been against the standards.

Although you used `:last-of-type` and worked in some browsers, the standard is that you use it on elements not classes.

Now in html, css, browser world you have to follow conventions and standards as much as you can, otherwise you can't predict the response and behavior of different browsers.

My solution (actually [j98691 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836886/last-of-type-is-not-applied/23837304#comment36678495_23836886)) was to use `:last-of-type` against an element i.e. a `span` element and enclose the three elements in a parent `div`.

I hope it's clear.

Comment: This solution works for me, but I don't actually understand the key difference from the OP. Could you please give some comment?

Comment: So if I correctly understand your answer, the only solution is to use a wrapper. And it isn't possible to perform my goal with my layout. Is it correct?

Comment: Read my edit and the key thing is that u use last-of-type only on elements not CLASSES , we mean by elements div p li a ul img. Etc

Comment: Ok, it's clearer now. But unfortunately it gives me some limitations (if was able to use classes, I could differenciate spans i.e. defining the first span of 3/6 width, the second with 1/6 width and the third with 2/6. With elements like spans, everything is forced to be equal sized. I agree, this goes beyond the OP, but unfortunately it's a limitation). Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: There r no limitations,  still u can assign classes to spans and set the css as you need, think of it and let me know, and don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if you accept it

Answer (score 0):

j08691 is correct.  last-of-type, nth-of-type, nth-child applies to elements, so if you want this behavior you should probably wrap your columns in another element and use: last-child.  This would be more reliable.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly in the OP's source is not according to the standard? The problem would be that whenever you have other divs later, the rule won't match. There is no syntactical error.

Comment: I suggested wrapping the elements in another element for that reason

Comment: You can disagree all you like, but you're still wrong. Show me where in the specs it says that you can't combine :last-of-type with a class name.